# Repeat fields in form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm writing an application where users can upload a maximum of 3 images to the application and was wondering if it was possible to have the same field repeated. My model looks like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    emailAddress = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Where when the image changes only the caption and image change, so only one email field would be needed. I have a form that uses my model to create the form. Would I have to create a static form then read all the data in from the HTTP request?

Comment: have a look at [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/)